# pandas - find index distance between batches of equal values in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find the "distance" between the starting points of two batches of `1`'s in a row or in other words the length of batches of "`1`'s followed by `0`'s" (indicated with spaces below).

So I start with the following series:

```
df = pd.Series([0,0, 1,1,1,0,0,  1,1,0,  1,1,1,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,0,0,0,  1,1,0,0])
```

and would like to get the following output:

```
0    NaN
1    5.0
2    3.0
3    7.0
4    6.0
5    NaN
```

I know how to get either the counts of the number of `1`'s in a row or the counts of the number of `0`'s in a row but I don't know how to deal with the case of this pattern of `1`'s followed by `0`'s as a pattern for its own...

Having NaN's at the beginning and end would be the ideal case but is not necessary.

Comment: show us what you have so far

Comment: To count the number of `1`'s in a row I used this line of code: `df.groupby(df.ne(df.shift()).cumsum()).agg("sum")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff()` to find the difference, `1` indicates starting of a new batch. Then you can use `np.diff` on the index:

```
s = df.diff().eq(1)
np.diff(s.index[s])

# or a one-liner
# np.diff(np.where(df.diff().eq(1))[0])
```

Output:

```
array([5, 3, 7, 6])
```

**Note** There is an edge case where the series starts with a `1`.

Comment: which you can add dummy 0 at the beginning of the series